# Unicode to String in java but tricky

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I was fetching data from a website using its API which was returning the data in `JSON` format.
The issue was when there where some umlaut characters in the `JSON`. It would return its `UNICODE`, for e.g. `Münich` would be `Mu\u0308nich`.

When I passed this `JSON` string to the constructor of the `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject`, `Mu\u0308nich` was converted to `Munich (n has an umlaut)`. Wrong.

I realized this very late (after fetching the entire data). Now I use the following method to convert it back to the `Unicode` form i.e. I pass `Munich (n has an umlaut)` to the method and it returns `Mu\u0308nich`.

I want to somehow convert this `Mu\u0308nich` to `Münich`. Any ideas?

Please note the conversion is needed only for `u\u0308` to `ü` and `o\u0308` to `ö` and `a\u0308` to `ä` and so on.

Method used to convert back -

```
public static String escapeUnicode(String input) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    Formatter f = new Formatter(b);
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (c < 128) {
            b.append(c);
        } else {
            f.format("\\u%04x", (int) c);
        }
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Comment: How can `chen` changed to `nich`, in Munich and Muchen?

Comment: @nhahtdh Typo. Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: I think the umlaut is dependent on how the program displays it (the umlaut is a separate character). Some program will fail to display the character correctly.

Comment: @nhahtdh - The problem is I already had the "correct" i.e. Münich in some cases. Now when I try to match it with this, n umlaut, data. I does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called [Diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) and you can use [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) to combine diacritics into single unicode characters.

Use the `normalize` method and as Form [`NFKC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html#NFKC). This will first decompose the full string into diacritics and then do a composition to return 'real' unicode umlauts.

So: 'München' stays 'München' and 'Mu\u0308nchen' will become 'München'

You then will have the string in a single format, not using diacritics anymore and easily portable and displayable.

If you work with texts from different platforms, some normalization is crucial or you will end up with the problems you described.

Comment: He doesn't want to get rid of them. He wants it to be displayed correctly.

Comment: He said: I want to somehow convert this Mu\u0308nich to Münich. Any ideas? and the above method does exactly this.

Comment: Sorry for jumping the gun, but I think you should say "combine them into 1 character" rather than "get rid of".

Comment: Edited, you're right. Combine sounds better than 'get rid of'.